# Given a list of KB numbers for Windows Updates, how can I find out what's in the updates?

Tags: windows-7, powershell, windows-update, updates

I have this issue with a program I work on, where the program behaves differently on my development machine v. the QA environment. I suspect the difference between the environments lies in which Windows updates are installed.

I have a list of updates on each machine, and have extracted the differences to find which updates are on the dev machine (app works) but not on the QA machines (app doesn't work). There are 61 updates on this last list.

I'd like an alternative to just installing the updates one-by-one, testing the app after each update. It would help if I could find a way to quickly get the kbase article text for each update. That way I could get some clues about which updates to look at first.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I might go about that?

Thanks.

Comment: You could attempt to screenscrape http://support.microsoft.com/kb/YOURARTICLENUMBERHERE

Comment: `http://support.microsoft.com/kb/<number>`

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, installing them and testing your apps is the recommended best practice.  Most people don't do one by one though.  When I did QA I'd do a batch of 4 or five at a time.  Try to use a VM and snapshot before each test.

In the comments someone recommended viewing the site page from microsoft on the update.  You should definitely do this.  Microsoft can't foresee every problem, but they usually give you a general idea of what an update does.  Dot Net updates should be tested thoroughly if you use Dot Net apps in your environment.